# Returning thumbnail image in imageview using JSON for a list

Tags: android, json, listview, imageview

Hi I'm having a problem with loading thumbnail images from this JSON url:

http://www.ilovelimerick.ie/?json=1&count=10

I can't seem to pinpoint the problem because it seems to work for posts, date & title. So why not for thumbnail?

Here is my code from the fragment:

```
public static final int NUMBER_OF_POSTS = 10;
public static final String TAG = NewsFragment.class.getSimpleName();
protected JSONObject mBlogData;
protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;

private final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private final String KEY_THUMBNAIL = "thumbnail";

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_list,
            container, false);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    if(NetworkIsAvailable())    {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        GetBlogPostsTask getBlogPostsTask = new GetBlogPostsTask();
        getBlogPostsTask.execute();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network is unavailable!",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //String message = getString(R.string.no_items);
    //Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    try {
    JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
    JSONObject jsonPost = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(position);
    String blogUrl = jsonPost.getString("url");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),BlogWebViewActivity.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(blogUrl));
    startActivity(intent);
}
    catch (JSONException e) {
        logException(e);
    }
}

private void logException(Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught!", e);
}

private boolean NetworkIsAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) 
    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isAvailable = true;
    }
    return isAvailable;
}

public void handleBlogResponse() {
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (mBlogData == null) {
        updateDisplayForError();
    }
    else { 
        try {
            JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blogPosts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                String date = post.getString(KEY_DATE);
                date = Html.fromHtml(date).toString();
                String thumbnail = post.getString(KEY_THUMBNAIL);
                thumbnail = Html.fromHtml(thumbnail).toString();

                HashMap<String, String> blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();
                blogPost.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
                blogPost.put(KEY_DATE, date);
                blogPost.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL, thumbnail);

                blogPosts.add(blogPost);
            }
            String[] keys = { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DATE, KEY_THUMBNAIL };
            int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), blogPosts, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            logException(e);
        }
    }

}


private void updateDisplayForError() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());   
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.error_title));
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.error_message));
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    TextView emptyTextView = (TextView) getListView().getEmptyView();
    emptyTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_items));
}

    private class GetBlogPostsTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
        int responseCode = -1;
        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.ilovelimerick.ie/?json=1&count=10");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            responseCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Unsuccessful HTTP response code: %d", responseCode));
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            logException(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logException(e);
        }           

        return jsonResponse;
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        mBlogData = result;
        handleBlogResponse();
    }

}
```

and also the .xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="235dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/empty" >

    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@android:id/list"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar problem, but I think the fix is simple.  Look at your code:

```
  1)  String[] keys = { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DATE, KEY_THUMBNAIL };

  2)  int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

  3)  SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), blogPosts, 
  4)         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, keys, ids);
  5)    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

What you are doing is wrong and you know that, if not, let me explain with aide of the line numbers I've added:

a) On line 1, you are creating an string array of your key values, you made an array of size three which holds 3 string objects [this is your first error and I'll explain why]

b) Line 2, you are making an int array to hold your id values. This only holds 2 objects unlike your keys array [2nd error & I'll explain what a) & b) are used for]

c) Now, on lines 3 & 4, you are creating a SimpleAdapter which is used by the setListAdapter to set the layout of each item in the list. Let me explain more clearly: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html -->official docs

SimpleAdapter sets the layout of each item in the list.
In the SimpleAdapter you created, you specified a keys array and an ids array to be used.

What the Simple Adapter does is loops through each blogPosts which is a HashMap key/value pairs, uses your keys array which should hold "title" & "author" with your ids array which accordingly hold two android system objects, TextView1 & TextView2 to set the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 layout.

As you can see the SimpleAdapter you chose only has 2 lines of text which I believe are TextViews. With the second parameter (blogPosts) in and grabs the value corresponding to the first key in your keys array, sets the simple_list_item_2 item layout's first line of text to that, in your case KEY_TITLE's value in blogPosts, and does the same for the next id in your ids array to set the layout's second, which is its last, line of text. So the result is as below:

-------------------------------a single list item by the SimpleAdpater---------

line 1: KEY_TITLE:  "Meet the Greatest Startup Yet"

line 2: KEY_AUTHOR: "Jeremy Author"

--------------------------------------End------------------------------------------

That SimpleAdapter does the same thing for each blogPost HashMap in your blogPosts ArrayList and when it's done, its used by the setListAdapter to populate your list.

What you wanted the SimpleAdapter to do is as below:

-------------------------------a single list item by the SimpleAdpater---------

line 1: KEY_TITLE:  "Meet the Greatest Startup Yet"

line 2: KEY_AUTHOR: "Jeremy Author"

line 3: KEY_THUMBNAIL: "{Picture Goes Here}"

---------------------------------------End-----------------------------------------

It can't do that because you passed android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 as your layout param.

**Here is the correct code with comments:**

```
/* these next few lines go hand in hand
            * ..we construct a String array called keys that holds our two keys, "title" and     "author"
            * ..then an int array that holds corresponding android system TextView ids
            * that will be used by the simple adadpter to display our content in the list view
            *
            * ..then we create our SimpleAdapter called adapter which will organize our blog posts in
            * android's simple_list_item_2 text view layout that has two lines.
            * for the paramenters of the SimpleAdapter, we pass in the context, the ArrayList of our blog posts
            * and the layout we want, the keys for accessing individual blog post's title and author values
            * from the blog posts ArrayList passed in param 2
            *
            * ..finally, we use setListAdapter to populate our ListView with the blog posts' title and author values
            * */
            String[] keys = { KEY_TITLE, KEY_AUTHOR };
            int[] ids = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, blogPosts,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    keys, ids);

            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

**My solution to this problem for now (Workaround)**

First, add a single ImageView above your ListView (or a Gallery to hold a bunch of pics) to hold the latest blog post's picture.

Then, get the latest blog post as a JSONObject, get the JSONArray for that object, get it's thumnail value, and use that thumbnail value to update the top ImageView's picture.

This is a workaround for your problem as I do not currently know how to add images beside ListView items.